# How to pay for something using my phone/sim credit?

Tags: ios

I am developing an iPhone application(`Swift 2.0`) which targets Metro bus system. It will help a person to pay for ticket using two ways:

1. bank account
2. Phone credit i.e the phone credit of the user will be deducted every
   time he pays for the ticket using his phone credit.

Now, I am not sure how to achieve **#2**. How can I make the user pay for the ticket using his phone credit.

I am new here, so I am sorry for any ambiguities in my question. I hope you understand what I want to ask.

I need ideas and clear explanations from you to achieve **#2**.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Apple doesn't allow charging to the cell phone account.

Comment: Dear Holly, thanks for comment. But i just want an idea of how to do it. I mean even if apple does not allow this, is there some way i can make my app send some sms to telephone service provider so that the phone balance is deducted and goes to metro bus organization.

Comment: There are no APIs in iOS for this. You would need to work with the phone carrier in order for them to provide some sort of billing interface.

Comment: Why not use apple pay?

Comment: Thanks Paulw11. I think i should see the phone carrier. But again there are different carriers so i will have to reach every single carrier for this. Or there is someway i can get it done in one go?

Comment: Swinny89, thanks but Apple pay works on iPhone 6 and greater. I want that my iphone app works from iphone 4 and greater so that everyone uses it. Also lots of people who travel using metro bus don't have bank accounts or credit cards, but i am sure everyone has phone credit which can help them pay easily.